# How to create Submit Button in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, submit-button

So to go straight to point.

Created database -> created table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Knjiga] (
[Osnovni_br]        INT            NOT NULL,
[Predmet]           NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
[Datum_prijema]     DATE           NULL,
[Datum_slanja]      DATE           NULL,
[Datum_proslijeda]  DATE           NULL,
[Posiljalac]        NVARCHAR (200) NULL,
[Adresa_posiljaoca] NVARCHAR (200) NULL,
[Primaoc]           NVARCHAR (200) NULL,
[Adresa_primaoca]   NVARCHAR (200) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Knjiga] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Osnovni_br] ASC));
```

Created this form

[PHOTO HERE](http://s28.postimg.org/vf40k2p99/prijem.jpg)
What I can't figure out (or find anywhere else for that mater) is how to create a Submit Button (lower right corner of image) for that Form that will

Enter data into Table.Knjiga -> Close that Form ->

Open next window that will only Show ID(Osnovni_br)/ordinal.

Comment: wait.... what???  you realize you need to write some code to do this right?

Comment: you may want to look into using MSAccess

Comment: @TMcKeown Yes, I do realize I need to write some code. But what I do not know is how to do it(still learning). Any help would be much appreciated.